# How to avoid double click on button in XAML / Mvvm / C#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I've got Button in Windows Phone project written in MVVM. Problem is that when I double press that button I will run my method twice, or more times. How to avoid that?

That's implementation:

## XAML View

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

## ViewModel

```
private readonly Command myButtonClick;
public ICommand MyCommand{ get { return myButtonClick; } }

{
   myButtonClick= new Command(MyMethod);
}
private async void MyMethod()
{
   // do work
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841332/prevent-double-click-from-double-firing-a-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to implement `DelegateCommand`, and check whether the button can be executed in `CanExecute` function. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476686/how-does-one-disable-a-button-in-wpf-using-the-mvvm-pattern/3476708#3476708))

Another way is disabling the button after button click and enabling when operation finishes.

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting Delegate Command and CanExecute.  Easily the best approach.